# Ring Group - How to make Asterisk just to save the last attempt

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I created a ring group on freepbx, for the option no answer I set the destination to this ring group that I created, just to be like a loop 'til someone hangup.

The problem... When someone calls to this ring group, asterisk register everything in the database, in other words, the 1st extension that rangs asterisk saves to database, the 2nd that rangs asterisk still saves to database and so on,  I know that this is right, but **there is a way to config that asterisk only register or save the last attempt?**

Answer (score 0):

Current asterisk version log every calls which "was offered for outgoing call"
No, you can't configure that.

However in some case you can put in cdr.conf

```
unanswered=no
```

If your extensions have qualify=yes, likly such calls will not be recorded(extension hints will be used).

Comment: But if I set this to no, all the unanswered call will not be registered, right?

Comment: Only if was no outbound call attempt.